# Как показать элемент в div где была нажата кнопка

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Поле</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/field.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <button id="start">Start</button>






  <div class="main">
    <div class="main_img">
      <img src="images/start-fild.png">
    </div>
    <p class="your_fields">
      Ваши поля: <br>
    </p>
    <div id="2" class="main_description__filds">
      <p>

        Статус: <br> Поле не обработано. <br> Нужно пахать.<br>
      </p>
      <p>
        Название поля: Стартовое </p>
      <p>
        Номер поля: 2 </p>
      <p>
        Обьем поля: 1 гектар
      </p>
      <p>
        <button id="2" name="vsh" class="btn" onclick="onStart('500');">Вспахать</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        Стоимость 1 гектара поля 100 000 $<br>
        <form method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="field_id" value="2">
          <input type="number" name="size" class="form" placeholder="Сколько гектар?"><br>
          <button name="expand" class="btn">Расширить поле</button>
        </form>
      </p>

    </div>
    <div id="6" class="main_description__filds">
      <p>

        Статус: <br> Поле не обработано. <br> Нужно пахать.<br>
      </p>
      <p>
        Название поля: Проверка </p>
      <p>
        Номер поля: 6 </p>
      <p>
        Обьем поля: 1 гектар
      </p>
      <p>
        <button id="6" name="vsh" class="btn" onclick="onStart('500');">Вспахать</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        Стоимость 1 гектара поля 100 000 $<br>
        <form method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="field_id" value="6">
          <input type="number" name="size" class="form" placeholder="Сколько гектар?"><br>
          <button name="expand" class="btn">Расширить поле</button>
        </form>
      </p>

    </div>
    <span id="time"></span>
    <button id="buy_field" class="btn">Купить поле</button>
    <div class="expand" style="display: none;">

    </div>

    <div class="main_registration">
      <a href="garage">гараж</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main_registration">
      <a href="storage">хранилище</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main_registration">
      <a href="square">площадь</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main_registration">
      <a href="mail">почта</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main_registration">
      <a href="profile?id=20">профиль</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/field.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script>
    var newDate,
      intervalId;
    if (localStorage["timer"]) {
      newDate = new Date(localStorage["timer"]);

      timer(); // Инициализация текста в элементах.
      intervalId = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    }

    function onStart(tm) {
      newDate = Date.now() + 60 * tm; // Таймер на 60 минут
      timer(); // Инициализация текста в элементах.
      if (!intervalId) intervalId = setInterval(timer, 1000);
      localStorage["timer"] = new Date(newDate).toISOString();
    }

    function timer() {
      var now = Date.now(),
        rest = newDate >= now ? Math.round((newDate - now) / 1000) * 1000 : 0,
        s = "";
      if (!rest) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = null;
        localStorage.removeItem("timer");
      } else {
        var rest2 = rest % 3600000;
        let hh = (rest - rest2) / 3600000;
        rest = rest2;

        rest2 = rest % 60000;
        let mm = (rest - rest2) / 60000;
        rest = rest2;

        rest2 = rest % 1000;
        let ss = (rest - rest2) / 1000;
        let ms = rest2;

        s = (hh < 10 ? "0" : "") + hh + ":" +
          (mm < 10 ? "0" : "") + mm + ":" +
          (ss < 10 ? "0" : "") + ss;
      }
      document.querySelector("#time").textContent = s;

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $span = $('#time');
      var $button = $('.main_description__filds button.btn');
      $button.click(function() {
        $.cookie('click', true);
        var $comment = $(this).parent().parent();
        $comment.prepend($('#time').show());
      });
      if ($.cookie('click' == true && $span.text() != '')) {
        var $comment = $('.main_description__filds button.btn').parent().parent();
        $comment.prepend($('#time').show());
      }
    });
  </script>
  <div class="main_copyright">
    <p>
      Вы вошли как - фантом <br> Ваш баланс: 94063324$ <br>
      <a href="logout.php">Выйти</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="main_copyright">
    <p>
      &copy; Все права защищены. <br>
      <a href="#">адрес сайта игры</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Всем привет. В кратце: span id="time" мне нужно вставлять в div в котором была нажата кнопка. Div'ы и кнопки выводятся с бд циклом и таких дивов будет минимум 1, максимум 5. На данный момент все правильно отображается до перезагрузки страницы. После нее во всех дивах отображается этот спан и время таймера, чего не должно быть. Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста решить эту проблему. Мозг кипит уже.

Comment: если у вас проблема не в самом пхп, а в JS то приведите сгенерированную html-верстку и js код.

Comment: >то приведите сгенерированную html-верстку. весь код перед вами. Что мне еще приводить?

Comment: передо мной пхп код, который выводит хтмл. если проблемы в пхп нет, то вставьте вместо него готовый html. ваш вопрос ведь не про пхп а про js, зачем тогда его и писать сюда?

Comment: код подправил. и мой вопрос не касается только php или js. вопрос глобальный! есть какой то вариант решения?